# Antlr non-LL(*) decision

Tags: parsing, antlr, grammar

I'm having some trouble creating part of my ANTLR grammar for my programming language.

I'm getting the error when the second part of the `type` declaration occurs:

```
public type
    :   ID ('.' ID)* ('?')? -> ^(R__Type ID ID* ('?')?)
    |   '(' type (',' type)*  ')' ('?')? -> ^(R__Type type* ('?')?)
    ;
```

I'm trying to either match:

- A line like `System.String` (works fine)
- A tuple such as `(System.String, System.Int32)`

The error occurs slightly higher up the tree, and states:

`[fatal] rule statement has non-LL(*) decision due to recursive rule invocations reachable from alts 1,2.  Resolve by left-factoring or using syntactic predicates or using backtrack=true option.`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The `type` rule you posted is not responsible for the error. You'll have to post a more complete grammar that that causes this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right, I managed to fix this a little earlier up the tree, by editing the rule that deals with variable declarations:

```
'my' ID (':' type '=' constant | ':' type | '=' constant) -> ^(R__VarDecl ID type? constant?)
```

So that it works like:

```
'my' ID
(
   ':' type ('=' constant)?
|   '=' constant
) -> ^(R__VarDecl ID type? constant?)
```

I got the idea from the example of syntactic predicates here:

https://wincent.com/wiki/ANTLR_predicates

Luckily I didn't need a predicate in the end!